# Problems with adding plugins on WordPress in localhost on WSL2

Tags: wordpress, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, local

I have an Ubuntu on my localhost on Windows (WSL2).

With installed WordPress in mounted folder on an external drive /mnt/c/projects/.

There is a problem when adding plugins in WordPress, it gives the following error

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$file' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in /mnt/c/projects/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php line 177`

Line 177 contains the following code:
`$file = trailingslashit( $file );`

```
    /**
     * Changes filesystem permissions.
     *
     * @since 2.5.0
     *
     * @param string    $file      Path to the file.
     * @param int|false $mode      Optional. The permissions as octal number, usually 0644 for files,
     *                             0755 for directories. Default false.
     * @param bool      $recursive Optional. If set to true, changes file permissions recursively.
     *                             Default false.
     * @return bool True on success, false on failure.
     */
    public function chmod( $file, $mode = false, $recursive = false ) {
        if ( ! $mode ) {
            if ( $this->is_file( $file ) ) {
                $mode = FS_CHMOD_FILE;
            } elseif ( $this->is_dir( $file ) ) {
                $mode = FS_CHMOD_DIR;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

//      if ( ! $recursive || ! $this->is_dir( $file ) ) {
//          return chmod( $file, $mode );
        }

        // Is a directory, and we want recursive.
        $file     = trailingslashit( $file );
        $filelist = $this->dirlist( $file );

        foreach ( (array) $filelist as $filename => $filemeta ) {
            $this->chmod( $file . $filename, $mode, $recursive );
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Many methods that I have encountered have been tried

- Changes max_execution_time limits, both in Apache php.ini and WordPress files
- Change define('fs_method' 'direct')
- Change the owner of folders
- Setting permissions 775 for folders and 644 for files

Change owner became possible after execution these commands

`sudo umount /mnt/c  sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c -o metadata`

Change permissions became possible after the creation of the file

etc/wsl.conf with thus content

```
[automount]
enabled=true
options="metadata"
mountFsTab = false
```

But only helped install plugins to comment out this part of the code,

```
/*
        // Is a directory, and we want recursive.
        $file     = trailingslashit( $file );
        $filelist = $this->dirlist( $file );

        foreach ( (array) $filelist as $filename => $filemeta ) {
            $this->chmod( $file . $filename, $mode, $recursive );
        }

        return true;
    }
*/
```

Comment: If what you posted is your current code, it would seem that you're not closing the function `public function chmod(...)` - take a closer look at where the closing curly brace is.

Comment: @FiddlingAway No, no,no.  It is code from wp-filesystem-direct.php